# Как работать с JS-шаблонизаторами?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Привет. В проекте возникла необходимость использовать JS-шаблонизаторы, но я я понятия не имею, как их использовать даже после изучения документации. Например, мне нужно вывести столько блоков, сколько содержится в json-массиве. Сейчас реализация такова:

```
<div class="carriers">
    ${(proposals[i].carriers).map(name => '<img src="//pics.avs.io/80/40/' + name + '@2x.png" alt="' + name + '" />').join('')}
</div>
```

В блок с классом `carriers` выводится то количество изображений, которое указано в массиве `["AF","PS"]`. Как добиться такого же функционала используя Handlebars.js?